# SQL Query Optimization with million of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently using below query to get record based on senderid. I have 2 million record in messagein table and also entries comes parallel in this table as well.
But it take morethen 5 sec to return result. This table having only one non-clustered index created on Providerid (include column priorityid, senderid,maskid)
Can any one sql expert help me out on this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextSmsQueue] @NoOfRow int,
                                        @GatewayId int
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN;
        CREATE TABLE #SmsIn ([Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
                             [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
                             [MaskId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
                             [Number] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
                             [Message] [nvarchar](1300) NOT NULL,
                             [SenderId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
                             [UDH] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                             [Credit] [int] NOT NULL,
                             [CurrentStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
                             [CheckDND] [bit] NULL,
                             [CheckFail] [bit] NULL,
                             [CheckBlackList] [bit] NULL,
                             [ProviderId] [int] NULL,
                             [PriorityId] [int] NULL,
                             [ScheduleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                             [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                             [EsmClass] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
                             [DataCoding] [int] NOT NULL,
                             [Priority] [int] NOT NULL,
                             [Interface] [int] NOT NULL);
        DECLARE @PriorityIn table ([PriorityId] [int] NOT NULL);
        DECLARE @COUNT bigint;

        INSERT INTO @PriorityIn
        SELECT PriorityId
        FROM PriorityProviders
        WHERE ProviderId = @GatewayId
          AND Type = 0;

        SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*)
        FROM MessageIn m
             LEFT JOIN @PriorityIn o ON m.PriorityId = o.PriorityId
        WHERE ((ProviderId IS NULL
            AND o.PriorityId IS NOT NULL)
            OR ProviderId = @GatewayId);

        IF @COUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #SmsIn ([Id],
                                [UserId],
                                [MaskId],
                                [Number],
                                [Message],
                                [SenderId],
                                [UDH],
                                [Credit],
                                [CurrentStatus],
                                [CheckDND],
                                [CheckFail],
                                [CheckBlackList],
                                [ProviderId],
                                [PriorityId],
                                [ScheduleDate],
                                [CreatedDate],
                                [EsmClass],
                                [DataCoding],
                                [Priority],
                                [Interface])
            (SELECT [Id],
                    [UserId],
                    [MaskId],
                    [Number],
                    [Message],
                    [SenderId],
                    [UDH],
                    [Credit],
                    [CurrentStatus],
                    [CheckDND],
                    [CheckFail],
                    [CheckBlackList],
                    [ProviderId],
                    [PriorityId],
                    [ScheduleDate],
                    [CreatedDate],
                    [EsmClass],
                    [DataCoding],
                    [Priority],
                    [Interface]
             FROM MessageIn
             WHERE MaskId IN (SELECT MaskId
                              FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SenderId ORDER BY ScheduleDate) AS RowNo,
                                           MaskId
                                    FROM MessageIn msg
                                         LEFT JOIN @PriorityIn o ON msg.PriorityId = o.PriorityId
                                    WHERE ((msg.ProviderId IS NULL
                                        AND o.PriorityId IS NOT NULL)
                                        OR msg.ProviderId = @GatewayId)) res
                              WHERE res.RowNo <= @NoOfRow));

            DELETE msgin
            FROM MessageIn msgin
                 INNER JOIN #SmsIn temp ON msgin.MaskId = temp.MaskId;
        END;
        SELECT *
        FROM #SmsIn;
        DROP TABLE #SmsIn;
        COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
    END CATCH;
```

Execution plan is available in Here:
[Execution  Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryXzThZSm)

Updated Query:

```
BEGIN TRY
begin tran;
CREATE TABLE #tmpMaskId (MaskId varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO #tmpMaskId(MaskId)
SELECT DISTINCT MaskId From 
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SenderId ORDER BY scheduledate ) AS RowNo, MaskId FROM MessageIn msg 
LEFT JOIN PriorityProviders o on o.ProviderId = @GatewayId AND o.Type = 0 and msg.PriorityId = o.PriorityId
WHERE  
((msg.ProviderId is null AND o.PriorityId is not null) OR msg.ProviderId = @GatewayId)
)as res WHERE res.RowNo <= @NoOfRow

Select [Id],[UserId],m.[MaskId],[Number],[Message],[SenderId],[UDH],[Credit],[CurrentStatus],[CheckDND],[CheckFail],[CheckBlackList],[ProviderId]
      ,[PriorityId],[ScheduleDate],[CreatedDate],[EsmClass],[DataCoding],[Priority],[Interface]
From MessageIn m inner join #tmpMaskId msk on m.MaskId = msk.MaskId

DELETE msgin
FROM MessageIn msgin
INNER JOIN #tmpMaskId temp ON msgin.MaskId=temp.MaskId

DROP TABLE #tmpMaskId
Commit;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
     END
END CATCH;
```

Comment: I don't see the execution plan that you mentioned...

Comment: You deleted the reference to the execution plan.  But the execution plan is going to help answer the question.  Please include an execution plan?  Or at the very least narrow down the scope of the question?  *(What part of the SP is taking the longest, the `INSERT INTO #SmsIn`?  How many rows does it insert, how many rows are in each of the source tables, have you tried the `SELECT` on its own to identify what part of that statement is slowing you down?  Reading this might help you make the question more answerable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: One low-hanging fruit optimization is to use `IF EXISTS` rather that `COUNT`.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but why are you inserting a bunch of data into a temporary table, then deleted the data in the source table that was just put in the Temporary table, and then dropping the temporary table? Just delete the needed data, don't duplicate it, compare it, and then delete both copies; that makes no sense. *Edit: If it's so you can get the deleted rows, (as I note the `select * from #SmsIn` before the `DROP TABLE`) then use `OUTPUT deleted.*` or similar.*

Comment: @Larnu : It ***is*** also selected out of the SP as a result before it's deleted from the temp table.

Comment: I have added the execution plan for your reference.

Comment: Add an index to your temporary table, probably on `MaskId`.  This has a high cost (21%) to perform a table scan at the moment.

Comment: You could try extracting the `IN` Clause [`WHERE MaskId IN (SELECT MaskId...`] into a temp table created before the insert and join to that instead of using an `IN` clause?

Comment: Use Temp table instead of table variable, apart from few other suggestion here.I don't think "second FROM MessageIn msg" is require with row_number()

Comment: @KumarHarsh instead of row_number what other option i have to select record from each senderid?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextSmsQueue]
@NoOfRow    INT
,@GatewayId INT
AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN;

CREATE TABLE #tmpMaskId (MaskId INT PRIMARY KEY)

DECLARE @PriorityIn TABLE ([PriorityId] [INT] NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @PriorityIn
SELECT PriorityId
FROM PriorityProviders
WHERE ProviderId=@GatewayId AND Type=0

INSERT INTO #tmpMaskId (MaskId)
SELECT DISTINCT MaskId
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SenderId ORDER BY ScheduleDate) AS RowNo
         ,MaskId
     FROM MessageIn msg
     WHERE ((msg.ProviderId IS NULL AND o.PriorityId IS NOT NULL) OR msg.ProviderId=@GatewayId)
     ) res
WHERE res.RowNo<=@NoOfRow

SELECT [Id]
    ,[UserId]
    ,[MaskId]
    ,[Number]
    ,[Message]
    ,[SenderId]
    ,[UDH]
    ,[Credit]
    ,[CurrentStatus]
    ,[CheckDND]
    ,[CheckFail]
    ,[CheckBlackList]
    ,[ProviderId]
    ,[PriorityId]
    ,[ScheduleDate]
    ,[CreatedDate]
    ,[EsmClass]
    ,[DataCoding]
    ,[Priority]
    ,[Interface]
FROM MessageIn mi
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmpMaskId AS tmi WHERE tmi.MaskId=mi.MaskId)

DELETE msgin
FROM MessageIn msgin
INNER JOIN #tmpMaskId temp ON msgin.MaskId=temp.MaskId

COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 
BEGIN
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;
END CATCH;

DROP TABLE #tmpMaskId
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, As per your requirement, I will only return record from this proc to send sms.After sms is successfully I send only require id from Message table to another proc to delete those records.

Technically it sound good.your existing proc is not slow because of delete.but its not ok  to delete before sending sms and again trying to insert.

In my previous scipt,I pointed that you do not need Join on PriorityProviders.

I have revise my script(INNER if possible),

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
    begin tran;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpMaskId (MaskId varchar(25) not null)

    INSERT INTO #tmpMaskId(MaskId)
    SELECT MaskId From 
    (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SenderId ORDER BY scheduledate ) AS RowNo, MaskId FROM MessageIn msg with(nolock)
    LEFT JOIN PriorityProviders with(nolock)
  o on o.ProviderId = msg.ProviderId and o.ProviderId= @GatewayId AND o.Type = 0 and msg.PriorityId = o.PriorityId

    WHERE  
    ((msg.ProviderId is null AND o.PriorityId is not null) OR msg.ProviderId = @GatewayId)
    )as res WHERE res.RowNo <= @NoOfRow

    CREATE TABLE #tmpMaskId (MaskId INT not null)
    create clusetered index ix_mask on #tmpMaskId


    Select [Id],[UserId],m.[MaskId],[Number],[Message],[SenderId],[UDH],[Credit],[CurrentStatus]
    ,[CheckDND],[CheckFail],[CheckBlackList],[ProviderId]
          ,[PriorityId],[ScheduleDate],[CreatedDate],[EsmClass],[DataCoding],[Priority],[Interface]
    From MessageIn m 
    inner join 
    #tmpMaskId msk 
    on m.MaskId = msk.MaskId

    DELETE msgin
    FROM MessageIn msgin
    where exists(select 1 from #tmpMaskId temp where msgin.MaskId=temp.MaskId)

    DROP TABLE #tmpMaskId

    Commit;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
         END
    END CATCH;
```

notice how I hv remove PK from Temp table and made it clustered Index.
How I hv remove `distinct` ?

Now main culprit is this statement,

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SenderId ORDER BY scheduledate ) AS RowNo
```

I think once if you comment it then proc will perform better.

Now you need only index.

Whichever column is most Selective make that column as Clustered Index.

Since I do not know selectivity of each column I can't say whether you should make `composite clustered` or `composite Non clustered index`.

If you go for `Composite Non Clustered index` then make ID as clustered index(PK) and keep the most `selective column on left side and so on`

`Composite Non Clustered index` can be (`maskid,ProviderId,SenderId,PriorityId`)Include(other columns of message table which are require in Resultset)

I am not telling you to remove `Row_number()`.Create `composite non clustered index` and rebuild index as I have describe above.

`With (nolock)` :It has nothing to do with data duplicity.
                     If there is no chance of getting uncommitted data.
                         If there is not much concurrency issue in message table and is not very frequently insert/updated.
Then you can safely use it.you can Google this "`Advantage and disadvantage of with (Nolock`)".
In one or two places you can use it if it improve your important query.

Like you said if you create index on maskid then it create deadlock.That is because of faulty script in Insert.

Comment: Thank for the reply, but i need a maskid group by because of a business scenario i can not use direct record then maskid. each maskid having sometimes 2 to 3 record. and sometime not. but anyways i need it.

Comment: @mayurRathod,by maskid did you mean table variable PriorityIn ?you didn't say why you want to return record after delete.and normally how many record will be deleted ?

Comment: Maskid is from MessageIn table. record is required to complete the process(sms sending). and max to max 500 record will be deleted at a time.

Comment: I need maskid to be varchar but i can reduce a length upto 25 character. which i have done. thanks for suggestion. Also when i make a non cluster index to maskid it include a deadlock in insert times. So currently i have only on index in messagein table that is Providerid (include column priorityid, senderid,maskid)

Comment: There is not any cluster index in this table. but only a id column have identity true with 1 increment. So currently not any primary key as well. MessageIn table have many concurrent request comes from api, web and smpp as well.

Comment: I have updated my question with some modification on query. in which now i have taken only maskid in temp table. but at the end i need all column from message table.

Comment: distinct because i have taken maskid as primary key on #tmpMaskId table otherwise it generate an error as i have multiple entries for same maskid. also select statement is required because i need a deleted record to further processing my request.

Comment: See my complete requirement is i need to take number of record(max 500) from message table to send sms and delete that record from message table. so i need select statement to send a message to that selected lot. If any error occurs at application level i will insert that record again in message table so next gateway will pickup this. I have multiple gateways which is picking up data one by one from this message table.

Comment: As i have seen you have used "with(nolock)" in message table. does it not gives me duplicate record some times. as i have read nolock should not be used with the data where duplicacy involved. what you say?

Comment: If i remove row_number part then the user have OTP sms make delayed in case of one user has done large push. in this case it only pickup that user message once first user all sms done. So this row_number help me out to deliver all user sms simultaneously.

Comment: @mayurRathod, read my edited answer "I am not telling you to remove Row_number()" onward